# Android SQLite ORDER BY a VARCHAR column with danish characters

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing a Danish Android application using SQLite. Now i am facing a problem i have a table "Category" with columns "id" and "name". I want to show alphabetically sorted categories in list view. But as categories name contain danish characters its not sorting in correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add `COLLATE LOCALIZED` to the `ORDER BY` clause. For example

```
SELECT id, name FROM Category ORDER BY name COLLATE LOCALIZED
```

would fetch all categories with ascending name

Comment: Can you write here sample query? to select all categories with ascending name.

Comment: @IrfanDANISH example added to answer.

Comment: This wont correctly sort danish characters but something like AÅÆBCDEFGHIJKLMNOØPRSTUVWX.

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your database simply do

```
database.setLocale(new Locale("da_DK"));
```

And everything will work as expected. Actually things will work better than expected as aa also gets picked up as å and gets ordered.